# Authorization Denied after moving EJBCA to another server

Tags: java, pki

So for some reason I have to move our PKI to another server. I stopped JBoss, dumped and restored database on the target box, and packed and moved the whole JBoss directory.

Now JBoss starts up without obvious errors, but I cannot access the administration interface. It says

> Authorization Denied
>
> Cause : Your certificate is revoked or cannot be located in the database.

Then I noticed that I cannot see my CAs on the public pages, e.g. "Fetch CA & OCSP certificates". So that's probably the reason for the above error.

How can I enable/import those CAs?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the database is not read properly. You should check JBoss logs during startup to find out the errors.